# Using angular directive in raw html within jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating `html` after getting `ajax` response, for example:

```
var html = '';
html = '<div ng-click="deleteRecord($event)">delete</delete>';
$('.main).append(html);
```

But `ng-click` directive does not work where as it work fine when added in html document directly. I don't have much understanding of how angular binds with DOM.

So I need some support for understanding if I can make this work when I am adding `html` through `jquery`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the HTML to your element, you can use the bindHtml directive included in the default Angular libraries.

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="someHtml"></div>
```

Just apply the HTML string to the someHtml property of your controller and it should work fine. Make sure to include ngSanitize (or '$sanitize') in your controller, as this makes sure no damaging HTML can be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `$apply()` after inserting your HTML. This forces angular to re-digest the bindings.

```
var html = '';
html = '<div ng-click="deleteRecord($event)">delete</delete>';
$('.main).append(html);
$scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.main').append($compile(html)($scope));
$scope.$apply();
```

Hope it helps.

PD: I'd try to avoid jQuery when using Angular.